# Typescript plugin for Eclipse not working

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to use the [Typescript Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript) by Palantir, and whenever I try to open a Typescript file, I keep getting this error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/node": error=13, Permission denied
```

I installed node globally with npm. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

a.) try reporting it here : https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript/issues

b.) Nodejs is installed in `/usr/local/bin` not `/usr/bin` so you can create a symlink to fix it : `"cd /usr/bin" "sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node"`